# Set first value of BehaviorSubject in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am pretty new into Rxjs. How can I set the first value of `BehaviorSubject` from a custom select box model who looks like this:

```
        private mainRangeDate: any = {beginDate: {year: 2018, month: 10, day: 9},
                                      endDate: {year: 2018, month: 10, day: 19}};

        constructor(public daterangeService: DaterangeService) { }

        ngOnInit() {
           console.log(this.mainRangeDate);
        }

        onDateRangeChanged(event: IMyDateRangeModel) {
           this.daterangeService.dateRangeInterval.next(event);
           console.log(event.beginDate);
        }
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DaterangeService {

  dateRangeInterval = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

  constructor() { }

}
```

The component template:

```
 <my-date-range-picker name="mydaterange" [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions"
                                 [(ngModel)]="mainRangeDate" (dateRangeChanged)="onDateRangeChanged($event)" required></my-date-range-picker>
```

I need to set `BehaviorSubject` to be `mainRangeDate` but I don't want to make it in `ngOnInit` or using a timeout.

Comment: Why do you don't want it to be set on ngOnInit ?

Comment: I need to use the `daterangeService.dateRangeInterval` in other components. I am displaying a table of orders based on this date interval; it won't happen anything if it doesn't have a value. Which onInit will be the first? Does it make sense?

Comment: In this case you can set this value from the ngOnInit of first component which will be using this service. If you are not sure that which component will use it at first then just set it from your root component.

Comment: *I don't want to make it in ngOnInit or using a timeout* - where do you want to set it then?

Comment: @AnkitKapoor - both components are on the same page. Setting from the root component might be a good solution.

Comment: If it solves your problem. Though instead of ngOnInit you can also use the constructor of root component as soon as service is available to be used.

Comment: @estus If both components are using the BehaviorSubject, I don't know which onInit method will come first. So I need to update the Subject's value with the default value of date range select box.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of how it's supposed to work in whole? If initial `mainRangeDate` is some hard-coded value, it should be defined in service and not in component. If initial value is dynamic and always based on select, you don't need BehaviourSubject.

Comment: @estus I understand what are you saying. So, after the login into my app I will get through an Observable within an http call to api the DATERANGE and then I set the BehaviorSubject value with the DATERANGE model. Also after that login I display data and get other kind of data based on this DATERANGE but the data have to wait for BehaviorSubject's first value - which is now waiting with a timeout (not ok).

Comment: You can make fetching the data wait on a valid value from your daterange observable by doing something like this: `daterangeService.dateRangeInterval.filter(x => x != null).switchMap(() => getYourData()).subscribe((data) => {})`. Just init the behavior subject with null or something you can identify as invalid.

Comment: You possibly have XY problem then. Components that depend on DaterangeService shouldn't be instantiated before request completion. This is a common problem that is usually solved with either APP_INITIALIZER, or route resolvers, or ngIf guards (depending on how 'login' is performed).

Comment: @estus Exactly! That's my big problem. How can I instantiate the service before request completion? I will dive deeper into APP_INITIALIZER. Thanks so much!

Comment: @estus - I managed to resolve all the stuff with APP_INITIALIZER. Thank you so much. Answer to the question with this one if you want :)

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that a value is asynchronously retrieved from back end, and a service is used by components that expect initial value to exist on service injection, initial value should be retrieved and assigned before these components are instantiated.

There are several ways to do this, one of them can be preferred depending on how the application works. `APP_INITIALIZER` provider allows to postpone application initialization. Route resolvers allow to postpone the initialization of route components. `ngIf` directive allows to postpone component compilation until initial value is ready.